# Use push notification from Gmail

Tags: email, notifications, gmail, google-cloud-messaging, push

I would like to write a android application that makes some actions when I receive an email. For that, I want to use push notifications from gmail server.
I have already used IMAP to read the inbox, but this is polling.

I have read tutorials to use GCM, but in my case I do not want to create a server but use one existing (here gmail) as some mail applications do.

Can you give me direction to follow please ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you already tried? I suggest researching the possibility of using GCM with a Gmail server.

Comment: I would like to know how register to Gmail server. Is there an specific URL ? Do I have to create a new project on Google API console ?

Answer (score 0):

Well ... it seems to be not possible to "connect" on Gmail server. (not found)

An other solution is to use IMAP with Idle feature. It works perfectly for me.

The different Email APK which exist and propose "push" notifications "cheat" using IMAP Idle.

The inconvenience is that the connection to the server shall be kept opened despite regular timeouts. So it is equivalent to do "polling".

I hope this "summary" will help someone ...